# Return odd elements with/without block

Tags: ruby, block, yield

I'm trying to return odd elements using this method

```
def odd_elements(array)
  retArr = Array.new
  array.each_with_index do |item, index|
    if block_given?
      yield(item)
    else
      retArr << item
    end if index % 2 != 0
  end

  return retArr
end
```

so that I could pass both these tests

```
it "should yield odd elements" do
  res = odd_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6])
  res.should be_an_instance_of Array
  res.should have(3).items
  res.should include(2)
  res.should include(4)
  res.should include(6)
end

it "should yield" do
  res = odd_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6]) {|x| x**2 }
  res.should be_an_instance_of Array
  res.should have(3).items
  res[0].should == 4
  res[1].should == 16
  res[2].should == 36
end
```

but I'm failing in the second one. It seems I don't understand how to yield and I didn't manage to get it right in two hours trying so many different things. Could you please explain me why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield` returns a value which you seem to want to add to `retArr`:

```
def odd_elements(array)
  retArr = []
  array.each_with_index do |item, index|
    retArr << (block_given? ? yield(item) : item) if index % 2 != 0
  end
  retArr
end
```

I would personally prefer `Enumerator` (if you are on Ruby 1.9.3+), a bit slower but arguably more readable and flexible:

```
def odd_elements(array)
  Enumerator.new do |e| 
    odd = false
    array.each do |x| 
      e << x if odd
      odd = ! odd
    end
  end
end

a = [1,2,3,4]

odd_elements(a).to_a #=> [2, 4]
odd_elements(a).map { |x| x * 2 } #=> [4, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
odd_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6]){|x|p x**2 } #note the p
#=> 4
#=> 16
#=> 36
```

It yields fine, but you never store the result in an array.

```
odd_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6]).map {|x| x**2 }
```

would save the result in an array.

Comment: Is there a way how to do that on the method side instead of the test side?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I think you can just change the `yield(item)` line to `retArr << yield(item)`.

Comment: @Ondrej The standard pattern is: yield items if there is a block (skipping a possibly big array); return an array if there is no block.

Comment: @steenslag Standard Ruby behavior without block is to return enumerator. Returning original reference can be a bad idea, depends on how you use it: `a = [1,2,3]; odd_numbers(a).clear; a #=> []`

Comment: @steenslag Well, I have to follow given tests. I'm not the one who designed them.